# matchedGeometryEffect does not animate smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to do a simple `matchedGeometryEffect` and it's not working. I've got a simple `Image` that has a fixed frame and I want to animate it to an `Image` that takes up the whole screen. This is how it looks like right now, as you can see, it doesn't transition smoothly:

[image]

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var enlarged = false
    @Namespace private var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if (enlarged) {
                Image("dunes")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: animation)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            } else {
                Image("dunes")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: animation)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 225)

            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                enlarged.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make `matchedGeometryEffect` animate smoothly, you have few rules to follow. You have to declare the frame after the `matchedGeometryEffect`. The animation has to be placed at the end of each image, instead of having it inside the `.tapGesture`.

Here is the code with the modifications:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var enlarged = false
  @Namespace private var namespace

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if enlarged {
        Image("dunes")
          .resizable()
          .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace)
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
          .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
          .animation(.easeInOut)
      }
      else {
        Image("dunes")
          .resizable()
          .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace)
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
          .frame(width: 300, height: 225)
          .animation(.easeInOut)

      }
    }
    .onTapGesture { enlarged.toggle() }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks, your code indeed works. However, when reading the docs, it doesn't say anywhere what you mentioned (about animation being placed at the end), neither does it say anything about frame. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)). Furthermore, I have seen examples where .animation call is not used. Can you please explain why? I will mark the answer as complete regardless, just curious if you can answer my question.

Comment: matchedGeometryEffect is a really good tool but it is buggy and need improvements, and as most of the Apple documentation, not everything can be found in it. The rule is that all modifiers and views you want to include in the transitioning has to be put before the matchedGeometryEffect. In this case, the two views do not share the same frame, so it has to be after. As for the animation, I like to keep them as close as possible to the view that they depend on to avoid unexpected related child view being animated. It would work the same on your ZStack, but not when triggered in the button.